# Regular expression for numbers with only one space in undefined positions

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i am trying to write a regular expression to validate the numbers with only one space in undefined places?

Maximum of 12 characters with one space or Maximum of 11 characters without spaces.

Ex: '25897 569874','5674','65783987665','435 6523'

i have tried with `^[0-9]{0,12}$`.this is not perfect cause  I don't know how to place the spaces and its counts.

Comment: What is the minimum number of digits in the string? Can a single space be matched?

Comment: @nhahtdh-maximum of 11 digits (with one spaces count so totally 12 characters ex:1234567890 2) or maximum of 11 digits (without space a count Ex:01234567891) but it can accept less than 11 digits also.

Comment: I'm asking whether empty string `''`, single space `' '`, leading space `' 234'`, trailing space `'45 '` are accepted by the regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh-Thanks for the above. It should allow leading space but shouldn't allow trailing space,single space and empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:\d{1,11}|(?=\d+ \d+$)[\d ]{3,12})$
```

`\d{1,11}` will match from 1 to 11 digits without space.

`(?=\d+ \d+$)[\d ]{3,12}` will match up to 11 digits with one space somewhere in the middle. The space cannot be leading or trailing, so `' 23'` will be rejected.

- `(?=\d+ \d+$)` is a look-ahead that matched one or more digit, then a space, then one or more digit, then anchor the end of string. It guarantees only one space will appear and the space will not be leading or trailing. The look-ahead also implicitly confirms that there are at least 3 characters in the string.
- `[\d ]{3,12}` will guarantee the string only contains digits or space, and up to 12 of them. The lower bound of number of repetition can be set to 3 or lower, since it has been implied by the look-ahead.

The 2 constraints together guarantees that text contains from 1 to 11 digits and an optional space at arbitrary position in between the digits.

---

To allow leading space, but reject single space, empty string and trailing spaces:

```
^(?:\d{1,11}|(?=\d* \d+$)[\d ]{2,12})$
```

Again, the look-ahead implies at least 2 characters, so the number of repetitions can be set to 2 or lower.

Comment: @nhahtdh-Thanks for the above sir.can you please help me how to add optional Special character say '#' followed by the above validation.Ex:0123 456789#12345?

Comment: @user1863261: I have edited to allow leading space. Please ask a new question if you want `#`, since your current question will change too much when you add that requirement. Please add more examples and description when you write a new question, since I don't know anything apart from your single example.

Comment: @nhahtdh The regular expressions listed do not address the poster's question adequately. The first expression will not match an embedded space in a number see http://regexr.com?331uh  and neither will the second see http://regexr.com?331ub. Which regex engine did you test this with?

Comment: @Anthill: Thanks. I didn't test at all and assume something in the syntax that doesn't exist. I have fixed the regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh The corrected expression is now valid :) Just for the record here's an alternative one: ^((?<JustNum>[\d]{1,11}$)|(?=.{1,12}$)(?<Mixed>[\d]+\s[\d]+|\s\d+))$

Comment: @Anthill: Can just simplify to `^((?<JustNum>\d{1,11}$)|(?=.{1,12}$)(?<Mixed>\d*\s\d+))$` I think the OP wants `  ` rather than `\s`, though.

Comment: Indeed - that's more succint :) - Note to asker of question: always a good idea to test answers too - all of us make mistakes too ;)

Comment: Last note: we can minimize backtracing in the alternate mixed expression by specializing the lookahead: `^((?<JustNum>\d{1,11}$)|(?=[\d\s]{1,12}$)(?<Mixed>\d* \d+))$`

Answer (score -1):

^[0-9 ]{0,12}$ will match upto 12 character string with or without space
If you need multiple criteria,
try OR operator (pipe): |

^[0-9 ]{0,12}$|another condition

Comment: This is for validation. Not for matching text.