# How to change this regular expression to work with .Net regular expression engine?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I am using regular expression to validate the mobile number with the following criteria:

1. Maximum of 12 numbers.
2. It should start with Zero.
3. Will allow only one space (at a non-defined point)
4. Followed by an optional extension number of up to five digits in length, not including the # sign

My Regular Expression looks like below: (I have tested this with "rubular" tester)

```
^((0((?=\d* \d*#)[\d ]{,11})(#\d{,5})?)|(0(?:\d{,10})(#\d{,5})?)|(0((?=\d* \d*$)[\d ]{,11})))$
```

But it's not working in .net regular expression engine.

Can someone tell me, in the above one which part doesn't work with .net regular expression engine? and if I can change anything in the above expression will it work in .Net regular expression engine?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but when you put this in C# you _do_ use a `@"..."` string rather than a `"..."` string, right?

Comment: Could you please post the C# code?

Comment: Please don't post the question [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717990/regular-expression-for-validating-numbers-with-one-space-and-one-optional-specia) and [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758870/how-to-validate-a-text-box-with-regular-expression-validator) and [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720282/regular-expression-to-validate-the-mobile-number-for-the-following-scenario) and [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717184/regular-expression-for-numbers-with-only-one-space-in-undefined-positions). Edit the (first) post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **only** problem in your regex is that you are not specifying the starting range anywhere.. so it should be `{0,11}` or `{1,11}` not `{,11}`

---

You can also use this simplified regex

```
^(?=(\S*[\s]\S*|\S*)$)0(\s?\d){1,11}\s?(#(\s?\d){1,5})?\s?$
```

`\S` matches any character that is not space

`(\S*[\s]\S*|\S*)$` matches 0 to many non space character followed by a space followed by 0 to many non space characters till end OR it matches all the non space character till end

`(?=)` is a `positive lookahead` which check if particular pattern occurs and if not it will not match!

Comment: Hi Thanks for your post.I have tested your above expression but its allowing more then one space.Ex:012345 678 92 .But it should not allow.can you please help me in this?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tested above one ,now its accepting only one space But its returning false if there is no space.(Ex:0123456789) But this should not happen.At most only one space or none.

Comment: Awesome... it's working now.Can u please give an explanation for the above one ?

Comment: `\S` with an upper case "S" also matches any character that is not a space.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes hmm...that makes it more compact..thxxx..edited the ans